# My PHP update password script is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been working on this script for awhile and I cannot get it right....

I know it is connecting because I can view my connections in the MySQL Workbench. It leads me to think that there is a problem with my UPDATE. Anyways could you guys please look look at it and tell me what you think?

```
<?php
//Connecting to the MySQL Database thing
mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "****", "*******") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("microcrith") or die(mysql_error()); 

//runs the code if submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

//makes sure there is no blank stuff
if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass'] | !$_POST['pass2'] ) {

    die('You did not complete all of the required fields');
}

//checking password to see if they match            
if ($_POST['pass'] != $_POST['pass2']) {
    die('Your passwords did not match. ');
}

//md5 encryption
$_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$_POST['pass'] = addslashes($_POST['pass']);
$_POST['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);
}
$newpassword = $_POST['pass'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];


//puts into database
$insert =  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$newpassword' WHERE           username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
$update_member = mysql_query($insert);
 ?>

<h1>Registered</h1>
<p>Thank you, you have changed password - you may now <a href="login.php">login</a>.        </p>

<?php 
} 
else 
{   
?>

<center>
<body style="background-image: url('http://microcrith.com/background.png');   background-repeat: no-repeat; background-cover: 0 0; background-size: cover;">     
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<table border="0">
<tr><td colspan=2 style="color:grey;"><h1>Profile</h1></td></tr> 
<tr><td style="color:grey;">Username:</td><td>
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="60">
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="color:grey;">Password:</td><td>
<input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="10">
</td></tr>      <tr><td style="color:grey;">Confirm Password:
</td><td>
<input type="password" name="pass2" maxlength="10">
</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan=2><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</th></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</center>

<?php
}
?>
```

Thank you for taking the time and looking at this.

UPDATE: Since everyone is saying this is so insecure I will just delete my website and start over.

Comment: There's a half dozen severe problems here but most of them stem from the fact that you're using coding practices that died out in the 1990s. Where did you get this from? You urgently need to consult with a guide on [proper use of PHP](http://www.phptherightway.com/) to avoid exposing your users to serious risk. You're putting `$_POST` data directly in a query and creating a [severe SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you're using the obsolete `mysql_query` interface.

Comment: Are we still doing the mysql_* cringe thing? Sorry I've been away...

Comment: @Leigh As long as people are posting code like this which is recklessly insecure, we'll have to keep posting those advisories. Sorry.

Comment: md5 is better than no encryption but not much better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could be the problem but try this :

```
 $insert =  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='".$password."' WHERE username='".$username."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also it's much prefered to use prepared statements with [php data objects](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead of mysql_* functions